# How to prevent autossh from becoming stuck once in a while?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel, autossh

I am using `autossh` to build a reverse ssh tunnel but from time to time the tunnel stops working and I need to kill autossh and start it again.

```
/etc/cron.d/autossh
@reboot autossh -f -nNT -R 3269:intranet.example.com:3269 public.example.com &
```

autossh seems to remain in a strange state, where the forwarded port is still open but you get no response from the other side. By restarting autossh this is solved.

How can I prevent this problem from occurring?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `ServerAliveInterval` (with a value in seconds) make the `ssh` *client* send a null (keepalive) packet over the encrypted channel every so often in order to detect a broken connection:

```
/etc/cron.d/autossh
@reboot autossh -f -nNT -R 3269:intranet.example.com:3269 -o ServerAliveInterval=30 public.example.com &
```

You should probably also set the corresponding `ClientAliveInterval` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your *server* to make the server drop dead client connections too:

```
# Drop dead client connections after 10 minutes of inactivity
ClientAliveInterval 600
```